# How to create fake users for your Facebook app for testing?

Tags: facebook

I am wondering how you test your Facebook app. Is there a Facebook sandbox with fake users that I can test the app during development?

Comment: What type of app are you testing? If it involves likes/recommends then just point to `http://example.com` it usually has tons of them.

Comment: Just want to get friends' names and location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application is using Facebook's Graph API, Facebook has exposed the ability to create test users for that purpose.  See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users  They currently have a limit of 100 test users created in this manner for your application.